Power BI divide measure is ignoring the slicers and returns the blank columns
The divide measure shows the blank months/years even though my slicers are selected to one year.
If I remove the divide measure, the data works fine based on the filter.
Even I tried to filter the date field but no luck.
enter image description here
Even using the divide measure, it should work normally based on the slicer selection.

it's because you are using ALL function. That will ignore slicers. pls provide some sample data and expected output

Switch ALL to ALLSELECTED.  See ALLSELECTED
Tip: DIVIDE function vs. divide operator (/)
